# Given a list of lists of two timestamps, how to check if the index of a dataframe is inside those datetime range?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reduce, mask

I have a list of lists of two elements with type `pd.Timestamp`, e.g.:

```
intervals = [
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 02:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 03:00:00')], 
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 05:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 07:00:00')],
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 07:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 08:00:00')],
]
```

I also have a sample dataframe, e.g.:

```
data = {'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
index = [
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 01:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 02:00:00'), 
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 03:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 04:00:00'),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
```

Now, how can I check if the index of the dataframe is inside all the datetime intervals? In other words, for every element of the index of the dataframe (a row) check if that row is contained in the first interval, or in the second interval, or in the third intervals, and so on by doing something like:

```
for start, end in intervals:
    df.index >= start & df.index >= end
```

My idea was to:

1. Create a boolean mask for each interval that check if every element of the index is inside the interval

```
masks = [
   [False, True, True, False],
   [False, False, False, False],
   [False, False, False, False],
]
```

2. Reduce the above list of masks into a single mask by applying the | (logical or) operator

```
mask = [False, True, True, False]
```

I wish to do 1 and 2 in a vectorized manner, so I would like to use numpy or pandas when possible. I am managing the data structure in Python with lists though at the moment. Which is the fastest way and which is the most elegant one also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) with [`get_indexer_for`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer_for.html) to identify the existing matches, then [`all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) to aggregate:

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(list(map(tuple, intervals)), closed='both')
# or
# idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(*zip(*intervals), closed='both')

out = (idx.get_indexer_for(df.index) != -1).all()
```

Output: `False`

How it works:

```
idx.get_indexer_for(df.index)
# array([-1,  0,  0, -1])

# check if values are found
idx.get_indexer_for(df.index) != -1
# array([False, True,  True, False])

# are all values found?
(idx.get_indexer_for(df.index) != -1).all()
# False
```

##### checking which elements are inside a range:

```
which = idx.get_indexer_for(df.index) != -1
```

Output: `array([False, True,  True, False])`

##### all combinations

If you need to compare all combinations, use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
i = df.index.to_numpy()[:,None]
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(*zip(*intervals), closed='both')

out = (i >= idx.left) & (i <= idx.right)
```

Output:

```
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

Comment: I edited the question: I want logical or instead of and, and I wish to check which elements are inside the ranges so that I can slice later

Comment: @LucaM you already have that in the intermediates: `idx.get_indexer_for(df.index) != -1` gives you a boolean array `array([False, False,  True, False])` and `idx.get_indexer_for(df.index)` gives you the positions `array([-1, -1,  0, -1])` (= absent/absent/match 0/absent)

Comment: are the intervals non-overlapping?

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding you but I believe my desidered output should be [False, True, True, False] because only the middle elements of the index (2° and 3° one) are inside the first interval, none are inside the other intervals. Reducing with logical or, the output should be as mentioned. Is that right?

Comment: The intervals should be non-overlapping

Comment: Also I might wish to be left-inclusive and right-esclusive on each interval (an "option")

Comment: Yes, I just added `closed='both'`, but default the left-boundary is excluded (to do it per interval directly use an `Interval` object). I also added a numpy alternative, but unless you really need the 2D intermediate I'd advise against it and it computes all combinations.

Comment: As long as the intervals are non overlapping this is fantastic. Another option would be with a binary search

Comment: @sammywemmy if the intervals are overlapping you can consider [`get_indexer_non_unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer_non_unique.html), although the exact logic remains to be defined ;)

Comment: That's why I suggest binary search, especially if the starts and end are monotonic increasing. It is the logic that powers `conditional_join`. With `get_indexer_non_unique` you might have to use a for loop, which may not be performant as d data size increases

Comment: @mozway I noticed with pandas 2.1 update this changelog: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/52628
The closed parameter seems to be unused. How to enforce this logic outside of the constructor of intervalindex then?

Comment: @sammywemmy would you mind elaborating more on your solution with binary search and the concept of conditional join? I'm new to this concept and I would like to understand. Maybe you can add an answer as well if possible. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method:

```
# Function to check if a date is in any of the intervals
def in_intervals(date, intervals):
    return any(start <= date <= end for start, end in intervals)

# Apply the function to each row
df['within_intervals'] = df.index.to_series().apply(in_intervals, intervals=intervals)

print(df)



                       value  within_intervals
2023-01-01 01:00:00      1             False
2023-01-01 02:00:00      2              True
2023-01-01 03:00:00      3              True
2023-01-01 04:00:00      4             False
```

Comment: Thank your for your alternative solution. I believe since the other solution makes use of pandas function, the solution should be vectorized and run faster than applying a custom function for every row. Do you know how to compare the performance of the two solutions?

Comment: @LucaM: In jupyter notebook, you can use `%%timeit` to check runtime of a code. Comparing the runtime you can evaluate the performance. In python code the following code should work:
`import time
begin = time.time()
"your code"
end = time.time()
print(f"Total runtime of the program is {end - begin}")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



intervals = [
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 02:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 03:00:00')],
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 05:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 07:00:00')],
    [pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 07:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 08:00:00')],
]

data = {'value': [1, 2, 3, 4]}
index = [
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 01:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 02:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 03:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 04:00:00'),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)
"""
print(df.to_string())
                     value
2023-01-01 01:00:00      1
2023-01-01 02:00:00      2
2023-01-01 03:00:00      3
2023-01-01 04:00:00      4
"""

# Efficiently check if any row is within any interval
interval_starts = np.array([interval[0].to_numpy() for interval in intervals])#, dtype='datetime64[ns]')

interval_ends = np.array([interval[1].to_numpy() for interval in intervals])#, dtype='datetime64[ns]')

index_array = df.index.to_numpy()[:, None]
"""
print(index_array )

[['2023-01-01T01:00:00.000000000']
 ['2023-01-01T02:00:00.000000000']
 ['2023-01-01T03:00:00.000000000']
 ['2023-01-01T04:00:00.000000000']]

"""

out1 = (index_array >= interval_starts)
out2 = (index_array <= interval_ends)
out = (out1 & out2)
"""
print(out)
[[False False False]
 [ True False False]
 [ True False False]
 [False False False]]
"""

any_in_interval = out.any(axis=1)
"""
print(any_in_interval)
[False  True  True False]
"""
```